# Vertically and horizontally align

Tags: html, layout, alignment, css

My problem is the following:

I've vertically centered a div. However, I'd like to center another div horizontally.
The problem is that I don't manage to center it horizontally.

[Here are my (X)HTML and CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/fE9JR/)

(X)HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="strut"></div>
<div id="page">
    <div id="inner_page">
        <h1>Galidie "jQzz" Clément</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
}

#strut, #page {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#strut {
    height: 100%;
}

#page {
    border: 1px solid #c00;
}

#inner_page {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #c00;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
```

strut is the marker for vertically center an element. page is centered vertically. The idea is to try to center horizontally the inner_page block.

Should I use absolute position? Or anything else? Did I choose the good method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#page` is inline-block, so it will always take up the dimensions of its children. In this case, its only child is `#inner_page`, which is 750px, so they both will be the same size. This means you cannot really center it inside `#page`.

You can center `#page` itself by putting `text-align: center` on `body` for example.